# How to display text from EditText to ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I am a beginner in Android programming and would want to display text entered in EditText by user into ListView when user clicks button. The code I wrote is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    final EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);       
    final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);
    myListView.setAdapter(aa);      
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);     
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    String item;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            item = myEditText.getText().toString();
            //Toast.makeText(null, item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Problem here

        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Try to accept the correct answer that works perfectly. It will help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi asp_NewBee,
          You should add the newly entered EditText item into your list todoItems like below inside of onclick block. From your code

```
  myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String item;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                item = myEditText.getText().toString();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Problem here

// Add your input text to list as follows
              todoItems.add(item );  // Now list todoItems has been added with new item at end of list.

       aa.notifyDataSetChanged();   // So your list adapter to be refreshed with new item




            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think--On Button click  Layout for Button will be invisible & layout for list will be visible.

```
 doItems.add(item)
& After that  myListView.setAdapter(aa);
```